# Continue running long background task after API completed in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

currently I'm building API to insert data and I have method to send email after data inserted. I want to run Send Email methods to separate background task, and I want this Send Email methods to run instantly.

I have try to use `var task = Task.Run(() => SendEmail());` but it stop after the API is completed.

And i have research, some use `Hangfire` to do this, is it possible to do this without other library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Task.Run should work because it queues the work to the threadpool and the threadpool will execute the SendEmail method even if the action method is completed. Hangfire is a good option too if you haves lots of places whicj require background work8 like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it with [QueueUserWorkItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=net-5.0) which allocates a thread from the web server instead of the app. Anything you do in the app itself is unreliable because the app can be restarted for a number of reasons and the threads can be aborted.

I would challenge the wisdom of designing this, particularly around your error handling logic. If the email failed and you have already returned the request, you would not be able to alert the user and would not easily be able to retry or even log the failure without creating messy code.

One workaround is use a [HostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which can provide a "mini microservice" that runs within your application. Another method is simply to delegate the call to another service/app so that as soon as the request is made, you can return the call to the client as you want to do but allow that other app to handle errors/retries/logging/queuing.